# See all method calls in Android Studio debugger?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on an app that uses a lot of asynchrous calls and eventbus logic and so the code is hard to follow just from reading. I want to see which methods are called when I do certain basic use-paths. Is there a way to log which methods are getting called without going and putting a log statement/breakpoint in every method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open Profiler.
2. Run App.
3. Click on CPU in Profiler.
4. Then Select CPU Profiling mode as "Trace Java Methods".
5. Click "Record".
6. Do your asynchronous calls.
7. Click "Stop".
8. On the right side screen click "Top Down".

Success (happy coding)

[image]

Comment: I have to do this with startup code that's run when a work profile is provisioned. Meaning there is no process id to attach to until the code I want to examine is running. Is there a way to "record" code that's already ran?